# Why is $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times A_5$ not solvable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

We can write $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times A_5 > 1 \times A_5 > 1$ as a composition series, but why is $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times A_5$ not solvable? I know that $A_5$ is not solvable, but it is enough? I'm really having a bad time with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you proven the uniqueness of the Jordan Holder decomposition?

Comment: @hunter Yes, it is proved!

Comment: Subgroups and quotient groups of solvable groups are solvable.

Comment: So, as $A_5$ is not solvable and is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times A_5$, then the latter cant be solvable. Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help! I really appreciated that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a finite solvable group $G$, the composition factors of $G$ must be cyclic groups of prime order.

The composition factors of $\Bbb{Z}_2\times A_5$ are $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $A_5$. Since $A_5$ is not cyclic group of prime order, we conclude that $\Bbb{Z}_2\times A_5$ is not solvable.

Answer (score 2):

Every subgroup of a solvable group is solvable.   But $\mathbb Z_2×A_5$ has a subgroup  $\{1\}×A_5\cong A_5$, which is not solvable.